# Automate a slider with pause and resume functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and I would like to automate it with pause and resume functions. I found this great snippet of code that allows me to pause and resume, however, it only allows me to pause once.

I am struggling to figure out how to make it so the user can pause as many times as they like.

here is the complete code:

```
    $s = 1000;  // slide transition speed (for sliding carousel)
    $d = 5000;  // duration per slide

    $w = $('.slide').width(); // slide width

    function IntervalTimer(callback, interval) {

        var timerId, startTime, remaining = 0;
        var state = 0; //  0 = idle, 1 = running, 2 = paused, 3= resumed

        this.pause = function () {
            if (state != 1) return;

            remaining = interval - (new Date() - startTime);
            window.clearInterval(timerId);
            state = 2;

            $('.timer').stop(true, false)

        };

        this.resume = function () {
            if (state != 2) return;

            state = 3;
            window.setTimeout(this.timeoutCallback, remaining);

            $('.timer').animate({"width":$w}, remaining);
            $('.timer').animate({"width":0}, 0);

        };

        this.timeoutCallback = function () {
            if (state != 3) return;

            callback();

            startTime = new Date();
            timerId = window.setInterval(callback, interval);
            state = 1;
        };

        startTime = new Date();
        timerId = window.setInterval(callback, interval);
        state = 1;
    }

    var starttimer = new IntervalTimer(function () {
        autoSlider()
    }, $d);


    timer();

    $('.slider-content').hover(function(ev){
        starttimer.pause()
    }, function(ev){
        starttimer.resume()
    });

    function timer() {
        $('.timer').animate({"width":$w}, $d);
        $('.timer').animate({"width":0}, 0);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="slider-content">
    <div class="timer"></div>
    <div class="slide 1">
        <div class="hero-container">
            <div class="header-content-container">
                <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="col1"></div>
                    <div class="col2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-link"><a href=""></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide 2">
        <div class="hero-container">
            <div class="header-content-container">
                <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="col1"></div>
                    <div class="col2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-link"><a href=""></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide 3">
        <div class="hero-container">
            <div class="header-content-container">
                <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="col1"></div>
                    <div class="col2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-link"><a href=""></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide 4">
        <div class="hero-container">
            <div class="header-content-container">
                <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="col1"></div>
                    <div class="col2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-link"><a href=""></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide HTML as well so people can help you better.

Comment: @Taplar How can I do that?

Comment: @TheUnKnown give me a sec and I will post the HTML

Comment: @TheUnKnown I just added the HTML

Comment: Have you tried `timerId = window.setTimeout(this.timeoutCallback, interval);' in the resume function?

Comment: @imvain2 unfortunately that did not help. I have replaced `if (state != 1) return;` with `if(state == 0 || state == 2) return;` in the pause function which allows me to pause and resume multiple times but the timer gets messed up